# Fix Android layout (dp, margin etc.)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

although i read myself through several threads explaining the differences between dp,sp,px etc. and also tried to get a good layout,
I am still struggeling to get it done right for different phones.

I am using different fragments, but if I get help to make it all right in one fragment, I'm sure i will be able to fix the others on my own.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    <!--all paddings=0-->
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    ...

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentBase"
        class="...FragmentBase" />

    <!--other fragments-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

So im trying to get a proper layout in that fragmentBase, which looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    <!--all paddings=0-->>
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentBase"
        class="...FragmentBase" />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!--elements-->

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            <!--other stuff-->/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            <!--other stuff--> />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            <!--other stuff-->/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            <!--other stuff--> />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            <!--other stuff--> />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            <!--other stuff--> />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Sooooo. The problem is basically, that the scrollview in some cases is too long, in other cases too short. Having a fixed layout_height="400dp" seems to be a mistake.
Also setting the height of the two button-rows to 40dp and have one 40dp above the other, both starting from the bottom doesn't seem to be such a good decision, but those buttons got background-images, so I can't use wrap_content.

How would the layout be correct? I want the scrollView to start right under my "header", so android:layout_marginTop="40dp" is more or less fixed, while the two buttonrows should be at the very bottom of the screen.
I guess I want the scrollview to be dynamic length.

Plz help :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to help you out without rewriting all of the code above.
First I'll start by suggesting a few changes:

1. You could set the height of the two LinearLayouts that contain the buttons to 40dp and set the buttons's heights to "match_parent"
2. You could give both LinearLayouts that contain the buttons an id, let's say

   ```
   android:id="@+id/row1"
   ```

   and

   ```
   android:id="@+id/row2"
   ```

   Then set the bottom one (id=row2) to have

   ```
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   ```

   And the top one (id=row1) to have

   ```
   android:layout_above="@id/row2"
   ```
3. Once that is done you can set in the ScrollView the following parameters

   ```
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_above="@id/row1"
   ```

If I understood the problem, this should help. Hope what I wrote was usefull

Comment: That seems very helpful!
To what should I set the height of the ScrollView now? match_parent?

Comment: Yes, that way it will fill all the space between the top (minus 40dp of margin) and the LinearLayout(id=row1)

Comment: Okay great, that answers this topic.

Comment: If this solves your problem please mark it as solved, thank you

Comment: Done. It's a little off topic, but is there a way in relative layout to fill elements horizontally over the screen in like width-%?
With linLayouts I can do that with the weight-attribute, but androidStudio keeps telling me, that this is deprecated, but I don't know any better way to do so.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that android:layout_weight is deprecated, and it is the best way to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

try to add this code to your scrollview

```
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/linearlayout1"
```

and this

```
android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
```

to your 40 margin layout

this may help